# Efficient spark dataset operations when partitioned by overlapping columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset ("guid", "timestamp", "agt") like below

```
val df = List(Test("a", "1", null),
   Test("b", "2", "4"),
   Test("a", "1", "3"),
   Test("b", "2", "4"),
   Test("c", "1", "3"),
   Test("a", "6", "8"),
   Test("b", "2", "4"),
   Test("a", "1", "4")
```

I need to compute

- the minimum timestamp for each row when grouped by guid.
- The count for each key when grouped by (guid, timestamp)
- The agtM of row when grouped by guid and ordered by timestamp(desc) and then take first non empty agt else ""
- Drop duplicates

So the output will be like below.

```
+----+---------+---+-------+-----+----+
|guid|timestamp|agt|minimum|count|agtM|
+----+---------+---+-------+-----+----+
|   c|        1|  3|      1|    1|   3|
|   b|        2|  4|      2|    3|   4|
|   a|        1|   |      1|    3|   8|
|   a|        6|  8|      1|    1|   8|
+----+---------+---+-------+-----+----+
```

I have tried

```
val w = Window.partitionBy($"guid")

    val w1 = Window.partitionBy($"guid", $"timestamp")
    val w2 = Window.partitionBy($"guid").orderBy($"timestamp".desc).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

    val gg = df.toDS()
      .withColumn("minimum", min("timestamp").over(w))
      .withColumn("count", count("*").over(w1))
      .withColumn("agtM", coalesce(first($"agt", true).over(w2), lit("")))
      .dropDuplicates("guid", "timestamp")
```

The agtM calculation I am not so confident though. My target is to achieve minimum shuffling as in this scenario we first group by guid and then group by (guid, timestamp) and logically the second grouping should happen in the first created partition. the output is then grouped by guid and joined with another table. Both data are pretty huge (in TBs) so wanted to achieve this with minimum shuffling and didn't want to move the computation inside mapGroups later (I could have done the agtM calculation simply by filtering the group with non-empty agenttime and then maxBy timestamp). Can you please suggest the the best way to achieve the above?

**EDIT**

The agtM calculation has been fixed. Just to give more context for the operations ahead, union of output and another dataset(one extra field, we kept it dummy in the output) will then need to be grouped by key to produce final results. I was also thinking of calculating these values(except window w) inside each partition (mapPartitions), then take the list inside each partition as another list and do further calculation.

Comment: Your `w2` window spec doesn't seem to do anything related to your listed requirement for `agtM`, which should forward-fill `agtM` with the first non-empty `agt` in descending timestamp order.  But then your expected output of `8` corresponding to `""` seems to suggest that you actually want to back-fill with the last non-empty `agt`?

Comment: isn't this row `|   a|        1|   |      1|    3|   8|` supposed to be `|   a|        1|   3|      1|    2|   4|`?

Comment: @LeoCyou are right. I want to backfill with the last non-empty agt while traversing the list for a guid ordered by timestamp. The other way to compute the same is `df.toDS().filter(_.agt != "").groupByKey(r => r.guid).mapGroups((a, b) => {
val agtMObject = b.maxBy(p => p.timestamp)
TestWithagtM(agtMObject.guid, agtMObject.timestamp, agtMObject.agt, agtMObject.agtM)
})`
@RameshMaharjan (a, 1,  "") is the input and the last column should be 8 because if you groupBy a and then sort by timestamp desc, then 8 is the agt corresponding to 6 will become agtM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitioning it initially by guid and then working with the iterators will logically do less shuffling. Not sure about the effect if the data inside each group is huge.

```
df.toDS().groupByKey(_.guid).flatMapGroups((a,b) => {
          val list = b.toList
          val minimum = list.minBy(_.timestamp).timestamp
          val filteredList = list.filterNot(_.agt == "")
          val agtM = if(filteredList.isEmpty) "" else filteredList.maxBy(_.timestamp).agt
          list.groupBy(_.timestamp).map(r => (r._2.head.guid, r._1, r._2.head.agt, minimum, r._2.length, agtM))
        }).select($"_1".as("guid"), $"_2".as("timestamp"),
          $"_3".as("agt"), $"_4".as("minimum"), $"_5".as("count"), $"_6".as("agtM")).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To back-fill `agtM` with the last non-empty `agt` value, you can make use of `last("agt", ignoreNulls)` with `rowsBetween()` for `w2`:

```
val ds = Seq(
  ("a", "1", ""),
  ("b", "2", "4"),
  ("a", "1", "3"),
  ("b", "2", "4"),
  ("c", "1", "3"),
  ("a", "6", "8"),
  ("b", "2", "4"),
  ("a", "1", "4")
).toDF("guid", "timestamp", "agt").
  as[(String, String, String)]

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy($"guid")
val w1 = Window.partitionBy($"guid", $"timestamp")
val w2 = Window.partitionBy($"guid").orderBy($"timestamp".desc).
  rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

ds.
  withColumn("minimum", min("timestamp").over(w)).
  withColumn("count", count("*").over(w1)).
  withColumn("agt", when($"agt" =!= "", $"agt")).
  withColumn("agtM", last("agt", ignoreNulls = true).over(w2)).
  na.fill("", Seq("agt")).
  dropDuplicates("guid", "timestamp").
  show
// +----+---------+---+-------+-----+----+
// |guid|timestamp|agt|minimum|count|agtM|
// +----+---------+---+-------+-----+----+
// |   c|        1|  3|      1|    1|   3|
// |   b|        2|  4|      2|    3|   4|
// |   a|        1|   |      1|    3|   8|
// |   a|        6|  8|      1|    1|   8|
// +----+---------+---+-------+-----+----+
```

Given that each of your window specs `w`, `w1` and `w2` has its own specific requirement, I'm not sure much can be done to reduce shuffling.  You could explore non-window approaches, although the result dataset you intend to create appears to fit well with using window functions.

Comment: This doesn't work for the following dataset. 
`val ds = Seq(
      ("a", "1", "8"),
      ("b", "2", "4"),
      ("a", "1", "3"),
      ("b", "2", "4"),
      ("c", "1", ""),
      ("a", "6", ""),
      ("b", "2", "4"),
      ("a", "1", "4")
    ).toDF("guid", "timestamp", "agt").
      as[(String, String, String)]`
output: 
`|guid|timestamp|agt|minimum|count|agtM|
+----+---------+---+-------+-----+----+
|   c|        1|   |      1|    1|null|
|   b|        2|  4|      2|    3|   4|
|   a|        1|  8|      1|    3|   8|
|   a|        6|   |      1|    1|null|
`

Comment: That's what the result is supposed to be because the empty value in your new sample data is at the first row within the partition and the back-fill won't (and logically shouldn't) cross the partition boundary defined in the window spec.

Comment: In that case, the WindowSpec specified is wrong (I am not sure why WindowsSpec can't consider the entire boundary, I may not call it backfill if that is not logical), as it is not producing the desired result.
The desired one is (Please look at the updated WnSpec in original post)
`|guid|timestamp| agt|minimum|count|agtM|
+----+---------+----+-------------+-----+--------+
|   c|        1|null|            1|    1|        |
|   b|        2|   4|            2|    3|       4|
|   a|        1|   8|            1|    3|       8|
|   a|        6|null|            1|    1|       8|`

Comment: Window functions operate within individual window partitions.  If your requirement can be loosened to taking the closest previous or next non-null values, enlarging the row range to (unboundedPreceding, unboundedFollowing) would serve the purpose.  In such case, whether you use `first` or `last` might not matter much.

Answer (score 0):

> > I need to compute
> >         the minimum timestamp for each row when grouped by guid.
> >         The count for each key when grouped by (guid, timestamp)
> >         The agtM of row when grouped by guid and ordered by timestamp(desc) and then take first non empty agt else ""

Looking at your requirement, *you need to compute minimum of timestamp, agtM (latest) of agt on group of guid  and count when grouped by guid and timestamp*.  These requirement suggest that you would need *three groupings and three shufflings*.

**The first grouping and shuffling - to find the count**

```
val dfWithCount = df
      .groupBy("guid", "timestamp")
      .agg(count("guid").as("count"))
```

**The second and third grouping and shuffling**

*latest agt* i.e. agtM can be found by using `Window` function and *minimumn timestamp* can be found by using another `groupBy` and `aggregation`

```
val dfWithMinAndMax = df.withColumn("agtM", first("agt").over(windowSpec))
      .groupBy("guid", "agtM")
      .agg(min("timestamp").as("minimum")
      )
```

Finally you `join` both of the *dataframes*

```
val finalDF = dfWithCount.join(dfWithMinAndMax, Seq("guid"))
```

This would give you *correct dataframe* **but without agt**

```
+----+---------+-----+----+-------+
|guid|timestamp|count|agtM|minimum|
+----+---------+-----+----+-------+
|c   |1        |1    |3   |1      |
|b   |2        |3    |4   |2      |
|a   |1        |3    |8   |1      |
|a   |6        |1    |8   |1      |
+----+---------+-----+----+-------+
```

I guess `agt` is not that important but if you really need it then you would need another *grouping* and *shuffling* and *join*

```
val dfWithAgt = df.groupBy("guid", "timestamp").agg(min("agt").as("agt"))

finalDF.join(dfWithAgt, Seq("guid", "timestamp"))
```

which would give you

```
+----+---------+-----+----+-------+---+
|guid|timestamp|count|agtM|minimum|agt|
+----+---------+-----+----+-------+---+
|c   |1        |1    |3   |1      |3  |
|b   |2        |3    |4   |2      |4  |
|a   |1        |3    |8   |1      |   |
|a   |6        |1    |8   |1      |8  |
+----+---------+-----+----+-------+---+
```

Columns order can be done using `select`.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: your solution gives correct result. Unfortunately I need the agt as well in the final output (it will used in the successive operations).

Comment: I have used agt as well in the last part :) didn't you see that @subhodip?

Comment: I did see.. I am not sure, but can you please tell me if this is more efficient than the solution in the original post? this looks less performant, I might be wrong though. I agree there are different ways to achieve same, but is it possible to get the same result with 2 shuffling or less? what if i partition by guid and then call mapPartitions and convert the list into another dataset (already mapped by guid, even though multiple guids might exist) and then calculate agtM and minimum inside a partition?

Comment: Yes @subhodip, you are absolutely correct. the more shuffling the more inefficient a solution is .